# WebStorm will take up a lot of CPU resources when updating the changelist. Is there any way to improve it?

Tags: git, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Sometimes the changelist of WebStorm will become an updating state, which will take up a lot of CPU for a long time. I found that it is running `git status --ignored`. Because `node_modules is` very large, this command consumes resources. Is there any way to solve this problem?

I tried to search in the settings of WebStorm, but I didn't find the relevant options.

I also tried searching for a way to modify the default behavior of `git status --ignored`, but I didn't find a way.

The complete command of WebStorm when updating the changelist is:

```
git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false status --ignored --porcelain -z --
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--ignored` flag is used to get the list of ignored files to properly recognize and highlight them in the project tree and other places.
In most cases, this command just returns the list of ignored directories and works fast.

You can turn the `git.process.ignored` *Registry* flag (**Help | Find action...**, type `Registry...` to locate it) off to skip the flag. Ignored files will not be highlighted as such though and sometimes may behave as non-ignored in this case (e.g. highlighted as modified until explicit refresh if you change them via IDE).

See the comments in/subscribe to [IDEA-250152](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250152) for more info